# Password for Connection String

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string

I have this following connection string:

```
private static string connString = "data source=\"" +
                                       LIB.Environment.App.DirToAbsolutePath("").Replace('/', '\\') +
                                       "SOMETHING.sdf\"";
```

... this connection string works, but it is not secure. So now I want to add a password for this connection string.
So I've tried it like this:

```
private static string connString = "data source=\"" +
                                       LIB.Environment.App.DirToAbsolutePath("").Replace('/', '\\') +
                                       "SOMETHING.sdf\"" + "password=\""+"trial\"";
```

Is it even possible to add a password in that way? If yes, could someone of you please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: There is superb site for such questions - [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com). Also do not concatenate strings. Use formatting to get life easier - you missing space before password word.

Comment: Check out the  [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) class.  It has all kinds of helpful methods to break apart, and create connection strings programatically.

Comment: @Reniuz Thank you very much! This worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. You have to mention User Id and Password. You final connection string should be like as below.

```
data source="SOMETHING.sdf";User ID=userid;Password=pwd
```